# Извлечь значение свойства объекта, вложенного в объект

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такие объекты:

```
// Оплата
var money = {
    "Иванов Иван Иванович": {"Оклад": 30000, "Премия": 10000, "Вычет": -1000},
    "Петров Петр Петрович": {"Оклад": 40000, "Премия": 10000, "Вычет": -5000}
}
//Выпуск продукции
var products = {
    "Иванов Иван Иванович": 60.0,
    "Петров Петр Петрович": 90.0
}
```

Исходя из этих объектов нужно построить рейтинги, кто сколько сделал, кто сколько получил. Для этого нужно структуру первого объекта преобразовать к структуре второго (то есть сложить оклад, премию и вычет) чтобы получилось

```
var money = {
    "Иванов Иван Иванович": 39.0,
    "Петров Петр Петрович": 45.0
}
```

Как выяснить, имеет ли объект вложенные объекты?

Или как получить доступ к вложенному объекту, чтобы чтобы с помощью `typeof` определить тип значения (объект или число)?

То есть, если функция получает объект со вложенными объектами, то она сначала выполняет описанное выше преобразование, а потом строит рейтинги, в противном случае сразу строит рейтинги.

Comment: что Вы будите чувствовать когда к Вам подойдут сотрудники полиции и попросят предъявить документы, которые лежат у Вас в кармане пиджака. Но карман не простой! Один раз засунув в него руку он отдаст документы, другой раз там будет сидеть голодный крокодил, а в третьих там будет работающая мясорубка?
И вот Вы спрашиваете - куда класть документы выходя из дома, если есть только этот пиджак? Да фиг его знает куда! Вы должны продумать архитектуру чтобы не было волшебства.

Answer (score 2):

Если известно что данные полностью вадлидны, то функция будет выглядеть примерно так -

```
var money = {
    "Иванов Иван Иванович": {"Оклад": 30000, "Премия": 10000, "Вычет": -1000},
    "Петров Петр Петрович": {"Оклад": 40000, "Премия": 10000, "Вычет": -5000}
}
//Выпуск продукции
var products = {
    "Иванов Иван Иванович": 60.0,
    "Петров Петр Петрович": 90.0
}

const SALARY = "Оклад";
const BONUS = "Премия";
const DEDUCTION = "Вычет";

const calck = data => {
  let result = {};

  for( let name in data ){
    let info = data[ name ];

    let salary = info[ SALARY ];
    let bonus = info[ BONUS ];
    let deduction = info[ DEDUCTION ];

    result[ name ] = salary + bonus + deduction;
  }

  return result;
}

console.log( calck( money ) );
```

А так можно определить к какому типу принадлежит элемент -

```
let data = {
  "a": {},
  "b": 999,
  "c": {}
}

const isObject = item => item instanceof Object

Object.keys( data ).forEach( key => isObject( data[ key ] ) ? console.log( `${ key }: is Object` ) : console.log( `${ key } is not Object` ) );
```